# Ошибка при обновлении сертификата с помощью certbot

Tags: https, letsencrypt

Debian 9.4, nginx 1.13

Код ошибки: **SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE** - Сертификат истёк. При обновлении возникает ошибка:

> expected /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/fullchain.pem to be a symlink
>   Renewal configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/site.ru.conf is
>   broken. Skipping.

/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/site.ru.conf

```
# renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.19.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/site.ru
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/fullchain.pem

# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
authenticator = webroot
installer = None
account = 55669eca7dfdcfcf0f4fceb9f50f0352
[[webroot_map]]
site.ru = /var/www/html/site
```

Прошу помощи!

Comment: Ну хотя б показали бы содержимое этого файла, что ли

Comment: И да, вы видимо когда-то успели сломать симлинк? Проводили какие-то манипуляции с каталогом letsencrypt?

Comment: удалить все сертификаты и сгенирировать по новому?

Comment: Можно и так, только лучше не удалять, а переименовать каталог в letsencrypt_old например, чтобы остался бэкап на всякий случай. И больше не ломайте симлинки :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

letsencrypt переименовываем в letsencrypt_old:  `mv /etc/letsencrypt/ /etc/letsencrypt_old/`
Веб-сервер nginx пробрасываем на порт 80, затем: `letsencrypt certonly --email <your-email-address> -d <your-domain-name> --webroot -w /var/www/html/site`
Все работает!